# How can I create a .CIF file from x-ray diffraction data in a paper, for compound not found in crystallographic database

Tags: crystal-structure, open-source, space-groups, cif, vesta

I tried to recover a .CIF file (Crystallographic Information File) with the crystal structure for the compound discussed in a paper by Reuter *et. al.*<sup>[1]</sup>, strontium hydroxide octahydrate - $\ce{Sr(OH)2·8H2O}$ - from Cambridge Crystallographic Data Centre (CCDC), but couldn't find it. The paper itself has tables with information recovered from x-ray diffraction data, as shown below.

[image]

[image]

Is there any free software or open source tool where I can just type the data from these tables to assemble a crystal structure like the ones I'm used to download from the database? How can I do it?

I posted [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/132937/89908) in chemistry.stackexchange at first, before materials.stackexchange entered beta. As it went unanswered, I'm giving it a try here.

#### References:

1. Reuter, H.; Kamaha, S.; Zerzouf, O. Hydrogen Bonds in the Crystal Structure of Strontium Hydroxide Octahydrate Sr(OH)2 · 8H2O. *Zeitschrift für Naturforschung B* **2007,** *62* (2), 215–219. [DOI: 10.1515/znb-2007-0212](https://doi.org/10.1515/znb-2007-0212).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the free software [VESTA](https://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/download.html) for creating a new structure by following steps

1. From the file menu choose New structure
2. Go to Unit cell panel and choose the space group of the structure

[image]

3. Enter the lattice parameters in the same panel
4. Change to Structure parameters panel and enter x,y,z and U<sub>eq</sub> of each atom one by one

[image]

5. Save the structure and after verifying that the wyckoff positions displayed by the software matches with that of the publication, you can export it to cif.

Answer (score 8):

The journal requires that the data is deposited in CCDC, ICSD or CRYSTMET.

This one was apparently deposited in ICDC with the depository number CSD-417100 (the number is given in the paper, I don't have access to the database).

If you also don't have access to ICDC write an e-mail to the author asking for the CIF file. Most academics are happy to answer such requests.